# inline css background-size cover

Tags: css

i'm having the following css code

```
.imgf{
    background: url(/thatscooking/FotoTC/FotoTC/ALWIN01.JPG) no-repeat center center ; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

thats working as it should now i need to change the img with php so i'm trying to use inline css

```
 <div style="background: url(/thatscooking/FotoTC/FotoTC/ALWIN01.JPG) no-repeat center center" 
    style="background-size: cover"
    style="-webkit-background-size: cover" 
    style="-moz-background-size: cover" 
    style="-o-background-size: cover" 
    class="imgf ">
<div id="naamb"><p>Album Naam</p></div></div>
```

only now is the background-size cover not working and not showing up in firebug

am i using the inline css wrong ?

Comment: you shouldn't use in-element styles. Use css

Comment: I'm using it to be able to change it with php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use single `style` tag.

```
<div style="background: url(/thatscooking/FotoTC/FotoTC/ALWIN01.JPG) no-repeat center center;
            background-size: cover;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover; 
            -o-background-size: cover;" 
    class="imgf ">
<div id="naamb"><p>Album Naam</p></div></div>
```

Answer (score 22):

Use this code, cleaner than @RAS version:

```
background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center / cover;
```