# blogger - how do i change my header size?

Tags: blogger

i want my image is fill up on those yellow box

[image: header-image]

html code:

```html
    <div id='header-blanter' itemprop='mainEntity' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='https://schema.org/WPHeader'> 
    <div class=''> <b:section class='header' id='header' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='no'>
       <b:widget id='Header1' locked='true' title='Your Image (Header)' type='Header' version='1'>
         <b:widget-settings>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayUrl'>https://s2.vndb.org/sf/08/104108.jpg</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayHeight'>720</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='sectionWidth'>185</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='useImage'>true</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='shrinkToFit'>false</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='imagePlacement'>BEFORE_DESCRIPTION</b:widget-setting>
           <b:widget-setting name='displayWidth'>1280</b:widget-setting>
         </b:widget-settings>
         <b:includable id='main'> 
    <b:if cond='data:useImage'> 
    <b:if cond='data:imagePlacement == &quot;BEHIND&quot;'> 
    <b:if cond='data:mobile'> <div id='header-inner'> 
    <div class='titlewrapper' style='background: transparent'> 
    <h1 class='title' itemprop='headline' style='background: transparent; border-width: 0px'> 
    <b:include name='title'/> </h1> 
    </div>
```

javascript code: https://pastebin.com/UL4KtV1N

Comment: Does this answer your question? [inline css background-size cover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047784/inline-css-background-size-cover)

Comment: problem solved thank you